# Angular 4 Observable call service multiple times

Tags: angular

I want to search cities by country.

I have two different shared component:
First one for country search and this emit selected country id
then second shared component get this country id and passing to service
but it doesn't filter cities and return all cities in database.
When i debug rest servise:
if I don't pass countryId it is work and return all cities, 
but I pass countryId; a short while later countryId value change (null or 0)
and return whole cities.
What is wrong with this scenerio.
Thanks.

```html
//Component
export class CitySharedComponent implements OnInit {

  cities = new Array<City>();
  searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();
  public selectedCountryId = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  @Input() countryId: any;

  constructor(private service: CityService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.search(this.searchTerm$, this.selectedCountryId.getValue(), 1)
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.cities = results;
      });
  }

  onKeyup(searchText: string) {
    if (searchText != null)
      this.searchTerm$.next(searchText);
  }


  ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    if (changes['countryId']) {
      if (changes['countryId'].currentValue == null || changes['countryId'].currentValue == undefined) 
        changes['countryId'].currentValue = 0;
      this.cities = null;
      this.selectedCountryId.next(changes['countryId'].currentValue);
    }

  }
}

//Service
search(terms: Observable<string>, countryId, lang): Observable<City[]> {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `bearer ${this.auth_key}`);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return terms
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.http.get(`${this.url}/search/${countryId}/${lang}/${term}`, { headers })
        .map(data => data.json())
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, immediate error is that you did not subscribe to country id subject, that's why there's no changes when you emit new value from it - just no one is listening. You just picked first value in the `ngOnInit()` and passed it to `search()`. It will not ever change.

Apart from that, don't change anything in the `changes` collection. It's generally bad idea to change data that is not yours, so treat it as read-only collection. It can be done simpler: `this.selectedCountryId.next(changes['countryId'].currentValue || 0);`.

**UPDATE**

It can be done simpler. You don't have to make your service know about any observables at all. Let it just fetch raw values. Handling observables is separate concern.

```
//Component
export class CitySharedComponent implements OnInit {

  cities = new Array<City>();
  searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

  public selectedCountryId = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  // if you don't need to store this value for your component then
  // you can safely remove getter and this field.
  // just leave setter, it will be enough.
  private _countryId: any;

  @Input()
  get countryId: any {
    return this._countryId;
  }
  set countryId(value: any) {
    this._countryId = value;
    this.selectedCountryId.next(this._countryId || 0);
  }

  constructor(private service: CityService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchTerm$.distinctUntilChanged().combileLatest(
        this.selectedCountryId.distinctUntilChanged(), (_term, _countryId) => {
            return {
                term: _term,
                countryId: _countryId
            }
        }
    )
    .switchMap(t => this.service.search(t.term, t.countryId, 1))
    .subscribe(results => {
      this.cities = results;
    }); // and of course do not forget to unsubscribe from this
  }

  onKeyup(searchText: string) {
    if (searchText != null)
      this.searchTerm$.next(searchText);
  }

}

//Service
search(term: string, countryId, lang): Observable<City[]> {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', `bearer ${this.auth_key}`);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/search/${countryId}/${lang}/${term}`, { headers })
        .map(data => data.json());
}
```

Comment: First thanks for quickrespone. I changed code below, but it dosen't work. return all cities in DB.

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedCountryId.subscribe(data => {
      this.search(data);
    });
  }

  search(id:number){
    this.service.search(this.searchTerm$, id, 1)
    .subscribe(results => {
      this.cities = results;`enter code here`
    });
 }
but if I send hardcoded value in search (eg: countryId=25) it works as I expected.

Comment: @muratkurtun, I updated my answer. Originally I was answering from the phone, it's highly inconvenient to edit code on it :)

Answer (score 1):

Could not find a ngOnDestroy in your code . You need to unsubscribe your Observables in destroy.